# Textarea lineheight after scroll

Tags: html, css

I want to create something like quicknote and at first I thought it will be easy task.

HTML

```
<div class="quicknote">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.quicknote
{
    width: 308px;
    height: 400px;
    background: url('../images/note-bg.gif') 0 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.quicknote textarea
{
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    font: 12px/22px Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed #aeaeae;
    text-align: baseline;
}
```

Here is div which contains textarea. Textarea lineheight is set to 22px, when enter is pressed cursor is positioned on right place. (I know text is on the middle of the line). 
But when scroll happen it seems text is not scrolled for 22px. Check out screen cast video to see what happend.

http://screencast.com/t/RYsPD5DH

I probably wouldn't see this without those lines in background. Does anyone know what is wrong here?

**SOLUTION**

I think that I have solution but don't ask me why this works. With little help of jQuery:

```
$textarea.on('scroll', function() {
   $textarea.scrollTop($textarea.prop("scrollHeight"));
})
```

and experimenting with textarea height, on example 332px, 354px, it seems it works well. Because 332 isn't divided with 22, remineder is 2, when I changed above jQuery with:

```
$textarea.on('scroll', function() {
    $textarea.scrollTop($textarea.prop("scrollHeight")+2);
})
```

all start to work as expected as you can see here http://screencast.com/t/pfhNJoUrSQS.

Comment: Have you tried viewing it without the background image then?

Comment: working fine no issues [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/mtariq/p5m74/1/) also take off `overflow: hidden;` from ".quicknote textarea" to see the scrolling effect

Comment: @tariq not works, you do not see this issue because you haven't background.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working correctly with a 22px line height; however, you may want to remove the overflow:hidden property so that you can view scrolling.

Comment: It is same with or without scrolling.

Comment: OIC after re reading your post again and watching the video again, I finally see what you mean, that your IMAGE isn't scrolling.  Please be a little more descriptive in the future! :)  Let me think about this for a minute.

Comment: No, image should not move, background is static. As you see in video, after scroll textarea isn't scrolled for 22px and text is placed under line.

Comment: I cannot figure out what it is that I am supposed to be seeing.  What line are you talking about?

Comment: background is yellow with lines. That line :-)

Comment: So you want the text lines to move WITH the notebook lines, and match up with each other?  You just said that the image should not move, and it won't.  However, your text lines will move as you scroll, and the lines and "paper" won't scroll together.